# Subsetting data based off of dates from multiple rows

Tags: r, date, subset

I have data on patients who have readmitted to a hospital within 30 days of a previous admission at that hospital. Many patients will readmit several times, however we only are coding it as a readmission if it is within 30 days  of a prior admission.

Here is an example:

```
name    stay at hospital   admitdate    readmission
john doe       1            1/1/2018    no
john doe       2            1/21/2018   yes 
john doe       3            4/2/2018    no
john doe       4            10/2/2018   no
```

I'm looking to subset rows where readmission = yes and the row with readmission = no with the closest admission date to that row where readmission= yes.

For this example that means I would want to subset only the first two rows. I want to subset row two because readmission = "yes" and then I want to subset row 1 because the admit date 1/1/2018 is closest to the admit date from the readmission = "yes" row (admit date 1/21/2018).

```
df <- df
df1 <- df[df$Readmission == "no", ]
df2 <- aggregate(df1$Date, by = list(df$Name), FUN = "max")
df3 <- rbind(df[df$Readmission == "yes", ], df2)
```

This did not work because it pulls the "max" date where readmission = "no" (stay 4) but I want it to pull stay 1.

I want to output to give me a dataset of these two rows:

```
name    stay at hospital   admitdate    readmission
john doe    1             1/1/2018       no
john doe    2             1/21/2018      yes
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this the extent of your actual situation? Or would you likely have multiple observations where `readmission=="yes"` and you'd be looking for the closest observation to that one. I think that matters a bit for being able to provide you with a universal solution vs. a solution only for your example.

Comment: I will have multiple observations where readmission == "yes" and I'm looking for the closest observation to that one.